# Chart for ASP.NET won't get displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, charts

I'm using the integrated chart control in an aspx-website (.NET 4.0) and I'm not able to get it displayed. Here's my code (VB.NET):

```
Protected Sub CreateChart(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal KZ As DB_Kennzahl)
    Dim chart As New Chart
    chart.Height = Unit.Pixel(400)
    chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(800)

    Dim ca As New ChartArea
    ca.Name = "ChartArea"
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(ca)

    Dim seriesKZ As New Series
    seriesKZ.Name = KZ.Text
    seriesKZ.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
    seriesKZ.Color = Drawing.Color.Blue

    chart.Series.Add(seriesKZ)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim dp As New DataPoint
        dp.SetValueY(Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Item(6)))
        dp.AxisLabel = CStr(dr.Item("Datum"))
        seriesKZ.Points.Add(dp)
    Next

    chart.DataBind()
    plch_Chart.Controls.Add(chart)
End Sub
```

As you can see I'm using a table to fill the chart's data.
The chart is added to a simple placeholder.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plch_Chart" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Did I forget something to write in the code? I can't figure it out what's wrong. The code seems right because not even a single exception will get thrown.

EDIT: Web.config: (Only the parts which are affecting the chart)

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
    path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</handlers>

<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;Url=~\TempImageFiles\;" />

<httpHandlers>
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
      assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </controls>
```

Comment: Don't you need to set the X value for the DataPoints by using SetValueXY instead of SetValueY ?

Comment: No, the X value is not a "must". SetValueY is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry if I seem ignorant, I only use this kind of chart with a datasource; but is the call to `chart.DataBind()` really needed ? the MSDN says you should call it when data have to be bound to a datasource, and it's not the case in your code as you add the points one by one; so this method could clear the data if the datasource is empty.

Comment: Even with `chart.DataBind()` on comment, the chart isn't displayed. I even tried with `chart.DataSource = dt` and then use `DataBind()` like MSDN says, but again nothing is getting displayed. My web.config could also be a problem, but I don't see any wrong code in there. I edited the post so you can see my web.config too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web.config seems correct. Instead of adding your control to a place holder, can you create it directly in the page ?

`<asp:Chart ID="myChart" runat="server" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" Width="800px" Height="400px" ImageLocation="~/someTempFolder/myChartImage">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Serie1"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>`

Comment: First let me say thanks for helping me so much! Unfortunately still nothing get's displayed. If I add points manually in the aspx-site the chart is getting displayed, but as soon as I try to set the points programmatically with the code in the post, nothing get's displayed, even by creating the chart directly in the page like you said.

Comment: No problem. Instead of showing the chart control, you could try to save the generated image and then display it with a regular `<img/>` mark.
Instead of adding the control to the placeholder, do :

`myChart.SaveImage(pathImg + "myGraph.jpg")`

Then, in the page:

`<img src="myGraph.jpg">`

Protip: check if you have the sufficient rights to write in the output folder.

Comment: The generated image is just a white picture with 3 KB. It's getting saved properly in the specified folder, but as I said, nothing generated, just a white background. I really don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Can you check if the DataTable is not empty ?

Comment: I managed to display it now. When I try to do it with `DataSource = dt` it won't work and the saved picture is white, but when I do it with the `For Each` everything works just fine. I will do it now the way you said with `<img>`. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: No problem, I had hard times with MScharts :)